# Is the movement of a projectile in 2D a Holonomic system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, projectile, constrained-dynamics

Is the well known problem of the movement of a projectile, no friction, in two dimensions a [holonomic system](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Holonomic+Systems)?

If yes.. Why?

If Not.. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Yes,* a projectile confined to the $xz$-plane is a holonomic system, since the constraint $y=0$ is a [holonomic constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints).